# SpringBoot - CMS structure

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, content-management-system

I am implementing a Spring Boot application that will be a micro-service.

This micro-service is supposed to define a **CRUD** `@RestController` over a `CMS`.

Is there any standard way of doing this, or any library I can take advantage of?

i.e:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/simple/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getKey(@PathVariable final String key) {
    return getCmsKey(key);//Retrieve key
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/collection/{key}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<String> getKeys(@PathVariable final String key) {
    return getCmsListOfKeys(keys);//Retrieve collection of keys
}
```